# How to make a range of values in a loop change name of file in bash

Tags: bash

Its about 2500 CSV files who need to be replaced with and comma values and i need a script to select a range.

R000001.CSV....R000499 in 5 directories but filename needs to be changed with the for next loop.

I need some advice to make this script works.

BTW _1 its a mark for the processed files.

```
read -p "First Value: " f
read -p "Last Value: " l
read -p "Secuence $f to $l ... is correct press <enter> to continue or Ctrl+C to cancel"
for a in {$f..$l..1}
  do
     tr -d '\r' ';'< R*$f.CSV > R*$f_1.CSV

 done
```

Comment: _"who need to be replaced with and comma values"_  Please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
for a in $(seq -f '%06.0f' "$f" "$l")
do
    echo tr -d '\r' ';' <R*$a.CSV >R*${a}_1.CSV
done
```

Notes:

1. The expression `{$f..$l..1}` will not work because variables cannot be put inside of a *brace expansion*.
2. The utility `seq` can be used in place of brace expansion.  With the `-f` option, we can select the format that matches your file names.
3. Inside the loop, you want to reference `$a` rather than `$f`.
4. The expression `$f_1` will not work as you expect.  Both `_` and `1` are legal characters in shell variable names.  Consequently, the shell will try to find a shell variable named `f_1` and expand it.  That is not what you want.  Using braces around a shell variable name, such as `${f}_1`, avoids this.

#### Without `seq`

```
for ((i=$f; i<=$l; i++)) do j=$(printf '%06i' $i); tr '\r' ';'<"R$j.CSV" >"R${j}_1.CSV"; done
```

Or, written over multiple lines for clarity:

```
for ((i=$f; i<=$l; i++))
do
    j=$(printf '%06i' $i)
    tr '\r' ';'<"R$j.CSV" >"R${j}_1.CSV"
done
```

Comment: thanks John but seq command does not exists in osx snow leopard so i research more and now i got this..                                                               for ((i=$f; i<=$l; i++))
  do
    tr '\r' ';'< R*$i.CSV > R*${i}_1.CSV

 done

Comment: @Ralcala Yes, those `*` could cause problems.  See the updated answer for a variation on your code that should work (it works for me).  Separately, for whatever its worth, I checked the man pages that Apple puts online and it appears that, in the future, you will be able to use `seq`:  Apple [includes `seq`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/seq.1.html) in the current OSX version.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time John and your instructions. The script works thank you again.